# Bitbucket cluster authentication failed due to hazelcast.group.name and hazelcast.group.password

Tags: docker, ansible, bitbucket

Setup two nodes in AWS EC2 to form clustering. An error is appeared:

```
com.atlassian.stash.internal.cluster.NodeConnectionException: Cluster authentication failed. Please make sure all members share the same value for 'hazelcast.group.name' and 'hazelcast.group.password' in bitbucket.properties.
at com.atlassian.stash.internal.cluster.DefaultClusterJoinManager.accept(DefaultClusterJoinManager.java:102)
at com.atlassian.stash.internal.hazelcast.ClusterJoinSocketInterceptor.onAccept(ClusterJoinSocketInterceptor.java:49)
at com.hazelcast.nio.NodeIOService.interceptSocket(NodeIOService.java:300)
at com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpAcceptor$AcceptorIOThread.configureAndAssignSocket(TcpIpAcceptor.java:316)
at com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpAcceptor$AcceptorIOThread.access$1400(TcpIpAcceptor.java:138)
at com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpAcceptor$AcceptorIOThread$1.run(TcpIpAcceptor.java:305)
at com.hazelcast.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:227)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64)
at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80)

... 1 frame trimmed
```

My bitbucket.properties in the bitbucket shared folder is

```
server.port=8444
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=pkcs12
server.ssl.key-store=/etc/atlassian/bitbucket/tls.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-password=password
server.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.3
server.ssl.key-alias=bitbucket
hazelcast.network.multicast=false
hazelcast.network.tcpip=true
hazelcast.port=5701
hazelcast.group.name=bitbucket-cluster
hazelcast.group.password=password
hazelcast.network.tcpip.members=<node1_ip_address>:5701,<node2_ip_address>:5701
```

The bitbucket is setup by docker in ansible:

```yaml
- name: Start bitbucket container
  docker_container:
    name: "{{ bitbucket_container_name }}"
    image: "{{ bitbucket_docker_image }}:{{ docker_images.bitbucket.tag }}"
    state: started
    restart_policy: unless-stopped
    container_default_behavior: compatibility
    volumes:
      - "{{ bitbucket_shared_host_location }}:{{ bitbucket_shared_home }}/"
      - "{{ bitbucket_private_host_location }}:{{ bitbucket_home }}/"
      - "/etc/atlassian/bitbucket/tls.p12:/etc/atlassian/bitbucket/tls.p12"
    detach: true
    network_mode: default
    published_ports:
      - 5701:5701
      - "{{ bitbucket_https_port }}:8444"
    env:
    {
      "JDBC_DRIVER": "org.postgresql.Driver",
      "JDBC_URL": "jdbc:postgresql://{{ bitbucket_postgresql_host }}:{{ bitbucket_postgresql_nodeport }}/{{ bitbucket_postgresql_database }}",
      "JDBC_USER": "{{ bitbucket_postgresql_user }}",
      "JDBC_PASSWORD": "{{ bitbucket_postgresql_password }}",
      "JAVA_OPTS": "-Dcluster.node.name={{ inventory_hostname }} -Duser.timezone=Etc/GMT+0 -Dhazelcast.local.publicAddress={{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}:5701",
    }
    security_opts:
      - "label:disable"
```

Can anyone please shed some lights on?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue in the end. That is because the group name and password are verified before any other checks. By adding a line in

bitbucket.properties

```
hazelcast.node.authentication.enabled=false
```

The default value of the attribute above is true.

I don't know how/why does it work. But this line resolves the issue. I post the solution just in case someone encounter the similar issue.